# Redirecting to another page from a click/touch event on html5 <video> element in iPad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html5-video

I am autoplaying an html5  in a web app running in a UIWebView browser.  I would like for the user to be able to touch the screen and be redirected to a new page. Since the video is autoplayed, I am able to omit the controls altogether (and that part is all working just fine).  Is this redirection possible?

So far I have tried:

adding a link around the video tags
    `<a href="http://www.example.com"><video type='video/mp4' id="myVideo" width="800" height="568" src="video1.ipad.mp4" autoplay></video></a>`

adding an onClick event to the video tag itself
    `<video type='video/mp4' id="myVideo" width="800" height="568" src="video1.ipad.mp4" onClick="document.location.href='http://www.example.com';" autoplay></video>`

adding a div around the video with an onClick event (and then when that didn't work, increasing the div's z-index to make sure it was on top of the video)
    `<div onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com';" style="cursor:pointer; z-index:10;"><video type='video/mp4' id="myVideo" width="800" height="568" src="video1.ipad.mp4" autoplay></video></div>`

any ideas would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happened to find something that worked today while working on another project!  I thought I would post it here in case anyone else needs this functionality.

Basically, I created a link surrounding a transparent div that is the full size of the screen and sits on top of everything else via z-index.

```
<style>.videocontainer { position:absolute; width:1024px; height:768px; z-index:10000; }</style>

<a href="index.html"><div class="videocontainer"></div></a>
<video id="myVideo" width="1024" height="768" src="video/video1.ipad.mp4" autoplay></video>
```

Comment: I love you, just know that.

Answer (score 1):

Using your second approach (onclick) should work if you actually used the correct variable :)

```
<video type='video/mp4' id="myVideo" width="800" height="568" 
       src="video1.ipad.mp4" 
       onclick="window.location='http://www.example.com';" autoplay></video>
```

Note *window*, not *document*.

(disclaimer: didn't test this on iPad but worked in Chrome)

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work either in this case, acting the same way the previous solutions did with the video running and darkening slightly on a touch event, but not redirecting to a new url, either while playing or after it has stopped.

Comment: Can you try doing something else from onclick? Just to see if it's actually getting the event and not just redirect, or not getting it at all

Comment: I just tried `onClick="video.stop()"` and it didn't work either so I guess it's not getting the event at all...